# XSTL Email displays full link on outlook.com

Tags: xml, email, xslt, outlook, outlook.com

A link that is supposed to be behind an IMG is being displayed as [www.somewebsite.com] it comes out with the brackets as a functional link.

And only in outlook.com in the outlook application itself, it works fine just as in gmail.com

I have currently changed to this solution to pass in the IMG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="4.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="DynamicLink"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="DynamicLink"/>\
      <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
      <p> Some text </p>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried `<a href="{myUrl}"><xsl:value-of select="DynamicLink"/></a>` but that one was broken in both outlook app and outlook.com

The hard coded `<a href="">` works fine, but it removes functionality since the DynamicLink contains JSON data that needs to be parsed on the site. Previous solution used xml node swapping so I had a node  with inside another  node and I would swap those it worked in outlook and gmail but broke in outlook.com

Has anyone had this issue before, or is there a way to opt-out for a hardcoded link in case of outlook.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the whole issue might be just that in the href the link needs to include `"https://"`